# Tokenizing Autocomplete Text Entry -- how to set inital values

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

Beginner jquery question.  I am using the [Tokenizing Autocomplete Text Entry](http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/) plugin, with the goal being to create a similar input as the SO Tags feild.

I got it pretty much working, but the issue that I am having is that when I edit my Story model (/stories/1/edit)  the tags field appears blank (I guess the plugin makes a brand new text entry and hides the original text field that has my initial values)

My question is, how do I get this plugin (or sugest another plugin that can do it) to show the existing tags when editing.

Note: I am using Ruby on Rails

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [link](http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/) you provided:

> **Version 1.1 Released!**
>
> - [..]
> - Can now prepopulate the list by
>     settings **settings.prePopulate** with an
>     array  of {id: n, name: blah}
> - [..]

Comment: I saw that, but i thought that just prepopulated the entire set of values so it did not have to go to the server to get the set -- but indeed you are correct.

Comment: glad to hear that i could help

Answer (score 1):

I did this through php.
I use community builder with joomla so I used the cb api to define the user and then echo the value in the `value=""` in the field input.

You can also do this with a simple db query similar to

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM something WHERE id = ". (int) $myid;
$_CB_database->setQuery( $query );
$value = htmlspecialchars( cbUnHtmlspecialchars( $_CB_database->loadResult() ) );
```

Then in your `value=""` add

```
<?php echo $value; ?>
```

For me it pre-populates both the hidden input as well as the token.

Now if I can just figure out how to use this on multiple fields without conflicting.